# How to run ansible-playbook with variable options in a shell script?

Tags: shell, ansible

I would like to run a playbook from a shell script with variable options.
When I have double quotes around `${ansible_opts}`, running the playbook fails and I get the following error.
What is the problem?

```
myplaybook=$1
ansible_opts="--vault-password-file ~/vault_pass.txt \
              playbooks/foo_${myplaybook}.yml \
              -i special_hosts"            
ansible-playbook "${ansible_opts}" -v  | tee /home/logs/foo_"${myplaybook}".log
```

```
ERROR! the playbook: --vault-password-file ~/vault_pass.txt                 foo_${myplaybook}.yml                 -i special_hosts could not be found
```

Im on Ansible 2.9.21

Comment: You are passing the string as a single option, but you need it to be split into multiple options.  Easiest (not best) solution is to just remove the double quotes and do `ansible-playbook $ansible_opts ...`.  But don't do this until you understand the implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something this simple, it is probably sufficient to simply let the shell do word splitting by removing the double quotes:

```
ansible_opts="--vault-password-file ~/vault_pass.txt \
              playbooks/foo_${myplaybook}.yml \
              -i special_hosts"            
ansible-playbook ${ansible_opts} -v ...
```

If you are using a shell that supports arrays (eg, `bash`) you might consider:

```
ansible_opts=(--vault-password-file ~/vault_pass.txt
              playbooks/foo_"${myplaybook}".yml 
              -i special_hosts)            
ansible-playbook "${ansible_opts[@]}" -v ...
```

Or (mentioned only for completeness) you may consider:

```
eval ansible-playbook "$ansible_opts"
```